# How to make a comparative analysis between the decision-making robots and human?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, decision-making, cognitive-development

I have the challenge of finding a way to model, develop, validate and implement an artificial cognitive architecture for mobile robots for industrial environment. In my present scope of the questions is to establish a method for evaluating the level of "intelligence" of these robots, or generations of virtual or physical robots, from a comparison with the "intelligence" of human and other animals.

Comment: Welcome to Cognitive Sciences. What exactly is your question? It is an interesting topic, but the question is kind of broad. I don't think people will be very keen to generate a research question, hypotheses, experimental protocols, study design and suitable comparative outcome measures and test statistics for you...